# openGL stuck on 1.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, doesnt update when using oibaf ppa

Tags: intel-graphics, opengl

my machine has Intel 5500 on-board graphics and I need to upgrade my openGL to run an app im currently developing. This is the error message I get:

```
ERROR: In ../Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 545
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x7fffe5a34ef0): GL version 2.1 with the gpu_shader4 extension is not supported by your graphics driver but is required for the new OpenGL rendering backend. Please update your OpenGL driver. If you are using Mesa please make sure you have version 10.6.5 or later and make sure your driver in Mesa supports OpenGL 3.2.
```

I tried to upgrade my openGL using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I also used the oibaf ppa to no success. Even after this, when I type `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"`, I still see the following output:

```
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (4.4.0 - Build 20.19.15.4531)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!